# Did Hashirama have a son?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto* it us shown that Tsunade is Hashirama's granddaughter. Does that mean she is the daughter of Hashirama's son? So who is Hashirama's son ?

Answer (score 7):

Hashirama Senju and Mito Uzumaki did have an offspring. But it wasn't confirmed officially if they were male or female.

Also, the series doesn't give importance to Tsunade's parents, as a result of which, they were never revealed. It mainly focused on the relationship Tsunade and Hashirama had between them and her life later on.

From [Hashirama's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hashirama_Senju) and [Tsunade's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsunade) Wikia articles respectively:

[image]

[image]

So yes, Tsunade is Hashirama's granddaughter. But it is not known if it was Tsunade's father or mother who was Hashirama's child. And, nothing is officially declared about them.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so The first hokage is married to Kushina’s mother so Kushina is the daughter of The first hokage which means kushina has a sis who had lady tsunade so naruto is technicality lady tsunades cousin but I doubt it

Comment: Do you have any source for Kushina being Mito's daughter?